# Add aac single audio to MPEG DASH mpd files

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg, mpeg-dash

I am trying to add manually to the .mpd file the following code.

```
    <AdaptationSet contentType="audio" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" lang="English">
        <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="44100">
            <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="44100" media="http://localhost/audio.aac" startNumber="1">
            </SegmentTemplate>
        </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
```

But its not working, Does everything have to be segmented in .mpd files ? or can I have a single .acc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work! You have to package your media into a MPEG-DASH compliant format first. So yeah, it needs to be segmented. Plus for "audio/mp4" MIME type the media needs to be added to a MP4 container prior segmentation.

One can use open source tool like [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation/) for that purpose.